# Nested DTO - Error while sending back to Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dto

I have a DTO like below

```
[DataContract()]
public class LastLevel
{  
    [DataMember()]
    public string UID { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public List<LastLevel> Children { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public LastLevel Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Having `Children` property is not creating any mess but if I include `Parent` property, I am unable to send data back to client. It is showing following message.

**The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. 
Unable to read data from the transport connection. an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

Comment: You should enable WCF traces to understand what really causes this exception. It can be cyclic reference, max graph depth or something else.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is the exception from the trace log.

Comment: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter <Link>. The InnerException message was 'Object graph for type 'Intergraph.SPF.Server.Services.EDWPIDManagement.Contracts.Types.DTOs.RTVPIDObj' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.'.

Comment: Parent property is referensing Child, and Child referencing Parent - cyclic reference. Remove Parent at all, or make it instead ParentId. You should be able to restore hierarchy without actual Parent reference

Comment: What if I use (IsReference=True)

Comment: You will get funny situation, where will be such Reference hierarchy: Parent1->Child1->Parent1->Child1->Parent1->Child1 and up untill MaxGraph on WCF binding is reached, which is 32 by default. It will just explode either way.